# What characters do I need for The Fraught Returns achievement?

Tags: achievements, genshin-impact

In the Challengers Series V achievements tab, there is one last achievement that I couldn't figure out

*The Fraught Return* consists of not letting the Hydro Hypostasis revive itself by repelling the water droplets without destroying any of them

As I didn't fight it that much because I don't have a single character that uses its boss materials, I don't really know the ins and outs of its mechanics so I have to bring in my most durable and strongest characters to wipe it out

But the way I understand the achievement, I'd have to use Geo Traveler's burst and/or skill to block the water droplets during the finishing phase

That would make the traveler a weak spot in my party as mine only has 1-1-1 talents and I don't have any artifact set for them

Are there other ways of blocking those water droplets without destroying them?

Notes:

- Zhongli's pillar (C0 Zhongli) may accidentally destroy one of them because it does some geo damage
- Cryo keeps them in place but eats away at their shield (?), even non damaging ones such as Ayaka's dash
- Not tested: physical attacks that can stall them in place
- Not tested: hydro catalyst attacks that should deal no damage to them but keep them in place?
- Not tested: electrocharged but that may damage them as well

Comment: Using the traveller is the easiest and cheapest option. Level up your other characters so you're able to kill the hypostasis with 3 characters. Any other not full-built character you use, may it be a cryo or geo or whatever, has bad stats like the traveller and cannot be used for good.

Comment: I'd recommend using Ningguan personally as her wall would block the bubbles path

Comment: Also consider doing it multiplayer. Even if you don't have the needed characters a friend might!

Comment: just wanting to point out that enemy shields can be damaged by three different sources: damage, *poise* damage and elemental reactions. Each specific shield can be immune to one or more of these sources. The water droplets are vulnerable to reaction damage, so that is why Ayaka dash damages them even if it does not cause any "normal" damage. They are damaged by the reaction, not by the dash itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that in order to get this achievement, you don't need to block them all at once

During its revival phase, you can block one droplet and let the other two revive the hypostasis and fight it again until its next revival phase, where there will only be two droplets left, then you block one, let the hypostasis revive once more and fight it until its revival phase, where you're left with only one droplet to block

And then, you get the achievement